# How to add custom condition in custom rule

Tags: magento2, rules

I've created a custom rule in my extension using [this](https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/)

Now I want to add my custom conditions in a rule like order attribute, order billing address attribute and
order shipping address attribute...Using that link I've got this result
[image]

But I want to add something like this :

[image]

I've tried this link also to do this task [HERE](https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-custom-sales-rule-condition/)

But it is for sales rule so it also adds an extra link in sales rule also!
I'm working with condition rule very first time so I also don't exactly know it's flow.
Does anyone have any idea? Please Let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching on this topic I've found the solution!
I focused on Magento's default rule in that, analyse the code of
vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine.php

then follow same like the default and modify where needed!